# Defining model in migration not working for Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, data-migration, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Currently working on a data migration and having issues.
I have this in my migration file.

```
class DropTutorProfileTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tutor_accounts
  end

  class TutorAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
  end

  def change
    send_data_to_subject_tutor_account
    drop_table :tutor_profiles
  end

  private

  def send_data_to_subject_tutor_account
    TutorProfile.all.find_each do |tutor_profile|
      # data migration code here
      tutor_account.subjects << subject
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this migration, I get the following error.

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Subject(#70181814234340) expected, got #<DropTutorProfileTable::Subject id: 3, name: "Writing", academic_type: "academic"> which is an instance of DropTutorProfileTable::Subject(#70181808133400)
```

This is the first time I'm dealing with this issue. I've had other migrations where I define models in the migration and had no issues. Interestingly enough, when I output the class of the `TutorAccount` instance and the class of `Subject` instance, I get...

```
TutorAccount
DropTutorProfileTable::Subject
```

I have no idea what's going on here. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you double check the class `TutorAccount` is not defined in different place in your project but not nested ?

Comment: Are you trying to assign subjects from `tutor_profile` to `tutor_account`? To your last question that is “interesting” > you are defining a `Subject` class within this migration, so it would in fact be namespaced with `DropTutorProfileTable`

Comment: Also I would recommend explicitly creating a joins table like `TutorProfileSubject` rather than relying on `has_and_belongs_to_many`. There are several great examples of why that is a recommended approach.

Comment: @Shiko There is a `TutorAccount` and `Subject` model defined in my codebase. That is why I'm defining it in my migration so it doesn't conflict. @inveterateliterate The interesting thing is that `TutorAccount` is not namespaced, but `Subject` is. Both are defined inside the migration and inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`. I was considering an explicit join model as well, but for our purposes it was overkill. I got over this by just writing raw sql, but still want to figure this problem out.

Comment: Hey guys, I figured out what's happening. Thanks for your input. It helped me get to the answer. It had to do with some code that's not listed in `# data migration here`. @inveterateliterate's comment helped me realize what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution to this issue. The issue was how the instance of the class was being called within the migration. When making a direct call to the model defined in the migration in the migration code, it is namespaced for the migration. for instance.

```
class DropTutorProfileTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base; end

  def change
    Subject.new.class # Returns DropTutorProfileTable::Subject
    TutorProfile.subject.class # Returns Subject
  end
end
```

This makes sense since the `Subject` class is defined in the migration and is being called as its own entity. However, the class for associated subjects is defined by the `Subject` class that is defined in the codebase and not the migration. This is behavior that should be obvious if one understands plain ruby. I actually ran this code as an example and it validated my thesis. Thanks @inveterateliterate and @Shiko for pointing me in the right direction.